# Getting error while adding android emulator in android studio

Tags: android, android-emulator, virtualization

**How can i use android emulator to run apps in my pc . please suggest me a method**
*Unfortunately, your computer does not support hardware accelerated virtualization.
Here are some of your options:
 1) Use a physical device for testing
 2) Develop on a Windows/OSX computer with an Intel processor that supports VT-x and NX
 3) Develop on a Linux computer that supports VT-x or SVM
 4) Use an Android Virtual Device based on an ARM system image
   (This is 10x slower than hardware accelerated virtualization*

Answer (score 0):

You can try genymotion instead android emulator . Genymotion is an emulator using x86 architecture virtualization, making it much more efficient. [link](https://www.genymotion.com/fun-zone/)